# Input array to php

Tags: php, html

i have multiple variables as:

```
<input type = "text" name = "data[0]">
<input type = "text" name = "data[1]">
<input type = "text" name = "data[2]">
```

etc. and i would like to import them to php page. Also there may be n such cases, so i have to use

```
if(isset($_POST[''])){}
```

command here.... can you please suggest how to get all these variables into an array in php page. here i tried to save names as data0, data1 etc, but it doesnt help... if you can, provide an answer for that as well

Comment: `$_POST['data']` is your array, so a single value will be `$_POST['data'][0]`.

Comment: You can create name as data[] for all the three input in form and can retrieve it in form of array just like $_POST['data'].

Answer (score 0):

Your array is in:

```
$_POST['data']
```

And you will have 3 items in this array for each input from html.

```
$_POST['data'][0]
$_POST['data'][1]
$_POST['data'][2]
```

Also it's not needed to specify the index in html. You can use like this:

```
<input type = "text" name = "data[]">
<input type = "text" name = "data[]">
<input type = "text" name = "data[]">
```

And you will have the same result.

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type = "text" name = "data[]">
<input type = "text" name = "data[]">
<input type = "text" name = "data[]">
```

In PHP page

```
foreach($_POST['data'] as $data) {
// your logic goes here
}
```